# How to play a sound when a specific key is pressed?

Tags: java, event-handling, applet

I'm trying to create a drums applet. So every part of the drum has corresponding keys in the keyboard and if you press it, a sound plays. How do I play a sound using keys?

Comment: by learning to code in Java and code it. If you are "kinda new to java", a "simple drums applet" is way out of your league. Also: applets aren't much supported any longer. focus on learning basic Java, and after that proceed to go for technologies and frameworks that aren't on their way out yet

Comment: Okay.. so is there any way i can make it possible using basic java? At least a sample code to start with.

Comment: learn basic Java, and you will be able to make it, otherwise not

Comment: Maybe i have to start learning key events first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So you need the samples of the different drum kit sound, eg. Kick, Snare, Hihat, crash, etc. It's best if you have them in a `.wav` format. So what you've got to do is using `Event Handling`, play the corresponding audio when a key is pressed. Make sure all the audio samples are in the same directory as he current project is. Even though writing a code and just doing your homework for you is not a policy to be followed here, I'll write a structure that will explain the thing to you.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrumApplet extends Applet implements KeyListener{

    //declaring Audio variables
    AudioClip kick, snare, hat_close, hat_opem, crash, tom;

    @Override
    public void init(){
        kick = this.getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "kick.wav");
        snare = this.getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "snare.wav");
        //load all other audio samples

        addKeyListener(this); //to detect the press of a key
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        //display message as to which key to press to play a sound
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent K){

        char X = K.getKeyCode();
        if(X == 'K')
        kick.play(); //play kick.wav when K is pressed

        if(X == 'S')
        snare.play(); //play snare.wav when S is pressed

        if(X == 'T')
        tom.play(); //play tom.wav when T is pressed

        if(X == 'O')
        hat_open.play(); //play hat_open.wav when O is pressed

        //write if statements for the rest of the Keys

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent K){}

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent K){}

}
```

Hope this will help you understand.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very helpful.

Comment: just never use this as a serious reference. Applet instead of JApplet ... meaning this code was decent before Swing came into existence.

Comment: Learn java. However, before learning applets, you'd want to read this: [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)

Comment: @Stultuske is right. Applet is dead technology. Read the article at the link given above^ and you'll understand. I just made an answer since the OP asked something about applets.